# Is there a way to evaluate $\int_0^1 (y\eta)'(\eta^2)'dx$ with $\eta$ an arbitrary function and $yy'=\frac32$?

Tags: integration

The problem is that I want to show that, or find out if,

$$\int_0^1 (y\eta)'(\eta^2)'\geq0,$$

where $y(x)=\sqrt{3x+1}$ and $\eta:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ an arbitrary twice differentiable function. It can also be infinitely differentiable if need be.

I have tried integration by parts twice, once, and in so many different ways but to no avail. From the definition of $y$ we get $yy'=3/2$. Not sure if that is useful. Is there any hope for finding the information I need for this integral from the given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated inequality does not hold: As a counterexample one may take $\eta(x) = -x $, then one has
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (y(x)\eta(x))' (\eta(x)^2)' dx &= - \int_0^1 2x (y(x) + y'(x) x ) dx.
\end{align}
Obviously, 
The integral on the right-hand side is negative. One can even determine the explicit value - it is $-308/135$.

More abstract, suppose that your inequality holds for all $\eta$, then it would be possible to replace $\eta$ by $-\eta$. This would imply both $ \int_0^1 (y(x) \eta(x))' (\eta(x)^2)' dx  \ge 0$ and $ -\int_0^1 (y(x) \eta(x))' (\eta(x)^2)' dx  \ge 0$. Thus, we would have
$$ \int_0^1 (y(x) \eta(x))' (\eta(x)^2)' dx  = 0.$$
This is absurd.

Comment: well that was stupid of me not to try a function :/ . Thank you very much for taking the time to do this.